# Java compilation error of method

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java but I am stuck with following code:

```
public class Main(){

public String getPublicity(){
   return "watch on youtube: Mick en de stomende drol (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ)"
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.println(getPublicity);
}
}
```

It doesn't recognize my method, what's wrong?

Comment: `public class Main()` is wrong class declaration. It should be `public class Main`. Also while calling method you should use `System.out.println(getPublicity());`

Comment: Then it still doesn't compile as you are trying to access a non-static method from a static method.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say

Comment: futhermore it must be a static method `public static String getPublicity()`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7O8CjFHrJ8

Comment: and the getPublicity call needs braces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling another method from the main method in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848820/calling-another-method-from-the-main-method-in-java)

Comment: @Puce Braces are `{ }`, and Parenthesis are `( )`.

Comment: @WalterM Thanks, I'm not a native English speaker and they translate to the same word in German. There is also "brackets". Never sure which to use when. I hope you understand anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public class Main{

   public static String getPublicity(){
      return "watch on youtube: Mick en de stomende drol (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ)"
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println(getPublicity());
   }
}
```

or more Object Oriented:

```
public class Main{

   public String getPublicity(){
      return "watch on youtube: Mick en de stomende drol (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ)"
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      Main main = new Main();
      System.out.println(main.getPublicity());
   }
}
```